# how do I replace XML file in APK?

Tags: android, apk

I would like to include additional (per-user) data in each downloaded APK file. In other words, I have an existing APK file on server and would like to:

- replace file `/res/user_info.xml` in existing APK with dynamically generated XML file
- update and re-sign the whole package before user downloads it

**More info:** I know it can be done using aapt, apktool, jarsigner,... The problem is that the documentation is quite poor and I was unable to find (or develop) a working technique to re-pack the APK file. For instance `aapt` always puts the XML file in root path (`/`) no matter what I do. I am also unsure which resources need to be updated so that the APK file is valid again. Also, the existing XML files in `/res/` are compiled - do I need to do that with my XML file too? If yes, how do I do that? If no, should I put my XML file in `/res/raw/`?

**Question:** how do I replace an XML file in APK and repackage it? What steps are needed and which tools do I use?

Comment: well, apk is just a zip file with structured folder/files. so you can unzip it and do what ever you want and zip it again with apk extension.

Comment: In theory yes, but in practice you probably also need to compile XML files, add them to list of resources, re-sign,... and these are just things I know about. So I am wondering what the whole process is.

Comment: I don t know what kind of information you keep in the that xml file but if you just change the value data of xml not the key it should work.

Comment: Again, no. :) How am I supposed to change a value in a compiled XML file? And even if I could, why would it matter if I change just the value instead of the whole contents? Anyway, if you have the answer (the whole process, at least outlined), please post it.

Comment: I didn't knew that we can exactly do that even after creating apk. So interested in this. can u send me the link where you found that information. This way I will also come to know about a new thing and may be after that I may reach to a position where I can help you. Any ways +1 for your question.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - but [this link](http://pof.eslack.org/2011/02/18/edit-image-resources-inside-an-android-apk-file/) describes the process (which doesn't work btw, because `aapt add` places file in the wrong directory). The whole build process is outlined very nicely [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html#detailed-build).

Answer (score 5):

In this [writing](http://www.demirozali.com/?p=64) you can find the basic steps of unpacking and packing an apk file.

Basicly;

= Use `apktool.bat d -s sample.apk .\sample\` to decode only resources of the apk.(In your situation there is no need to decode source part)

= Add/edit/replace your required resources.

= Use `apktool.bat b .\sample\ .\sample_edited.apk` to build changed apk.

= Generate a RSA 2048 key to sign apk if you dont already have one : `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my.keystore -alias myandroidalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000`

= Sign apk with generated key `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my.keystore .\sample_edited.apk  -signedjar .\sample_signed.apk myandroidalias`

= And align signed apk with 4-byte boundary `zipalign.exe -v 4 .\sample_signed.apk .\sample_aligned.apk` (*zipalign comes with the android-sdk*)